# Cannot Trigger AssertionError in OpenERP 6.0.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I'm using OpenERP 6.0.4 and trying to use assert

```
assert False, "This message should prompt out"
```

but this is not being called, I've tried all the mode in openerp-server assert-exit-level

this happens only in Windows, when I'm trying it in Ubuntu it works fine, what should I do to enable assertions ? thanks

Answer (score -1):

assert True, "This message should prompt out"

try change False to True, there's some differences between Linux based OS and windows on Boolean calculation

Comment: it's not working too, but when I use python console in windows and use that line of code the AssertionError is prompted

Comment: python console in windows will calculate like linux one, but in windows itself it won't.

How about this?
assert 1, "This message should prompt out"

Comment: To do this, you have to set strict option to false

Comment: which strict option do you mean ?

Comment: fyi, assert keyword introduced in version 1.5.
make sure your windows runtime environment is at this version